# Python dict incomprehension

Tags: python, dictionary

(Sorry, couldn't resist the pun!)

I wonder why it doesn't seem possible to translate:

```
dict([(str(x),x) if x % 2 else (str(x),x*10) for x in range(10)])
```

into this more readable expression, using dict comprehension:

```
{str(x):x if x % 2 else str(x):x*10 for x in range(10)}
```

Comment: As a side note, the first one can be written as:  `dict((str(x),x if i%2 else x*10) for x in range(10))` for symmetry with thg435's solution.  (I also changed the list-comp to a generator, because ... why not?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
{ str(x):(x if x % 2 else x*10) for x in range(10) }
```

seems to work well

Comment: my advice `{str(x):(x if x % 2 else x*10) for x in range(10)}` - more readable one

Comment: @AlexeyKachayev: [This site is collaboratively edited](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), didn't you know? If you have a helpful suggestion, just edit the post!

Comment: Please be noted the dict comprehension is only available in v2.7+

Answer (score 1):

The precedence is set so that  the `if .. else` doesn't apply to the whole `key:value` pair: it is only part of the value. That means you want:

```
{str(x): (x if x % 2 else x*10 for x in range(10))}
```

In the unlikely event that you wanted a different key calculation, as well as a different value, in some cases, you would have to do it like this:

```
{(str(x) if x % 2 else repr(x)) : x if x % 2 else x * 10 }
```

which would be equivalent to:

```
dict([(str(x),x) if x % 2 else (repr(x),x*10) for x in range(10)])
```

Or decide that an explicit loop is more readable than a one-liner for something so complex.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's just a matter or grouping expressions properly:

```
# original
{str(x): (x if x % 2 else x*10) for x in range(10)}

# slightly more complex, allowing both key and value to have the ternary
{(str(x) if x % 3 else str(x+1)) : (x if x % 2 else x*10) for x in range(10)}
```